# .NET MAUI Blazor publishing fails (win64)

Tags: publish, maui-blazor

I'm trying out the new .NET MAUI Blazor App template that comes with VS 2022 17.2.0 Preview 2.0. The app runs fine when debugging, but when I try to publish the app to a folder, specifying net6.0-windows10.0.19041 as the target framework and win-x64 as the target runtime, I'm getting "Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error", and in the output window: "The RuntimeIdentifier 'win-x64' is invalid". Anyone else experiencing this, or is it just me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. It looks like a bug in the preview.

See here for more details. https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3493

Comment: Thanks for replying, Neil. I installed 17.2.0 preview 2.1 yesterday, but it seems the problem is still there.